# Parameter passing

Tags: c++, function, opencv, parameter-passing

In a program in the `Learning OpenCV` book:

```
void onTrackbarSlide(int pos)
{
cvSetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,pos);
}
```

And, in another location:

```
if(frames!=0)
{
cvCreateTrackbar("Position","Example3",&g_slider_position,frames,onTrackbarSlide);
}
```

If you see `onTrackbarSlide`, there is no parameter passed. In this case, what value will be passed to the `onTrackSlide(int pos)` method?

Comment: @Unapiedra. It is in page (20) - Chapter (2). Thanks

Comment: Quit writing tags in your titles please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the address of function

```
void onTrackbarSlide(int pos)
```

as the last parameter in the function `cvCreateTrackbar`

This doesn't call the `onTrackbarSlide`. The `cvCreateTrackbar` method must be storing the address of the function `onTrackbarSlide` and using it as an **Callback** to intimate of some asynchronous happening.